# Misplaced Constructs error (Java)

Tags: java, exception, syntax-error, try-catch, file-handling

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong in my program to get this error? I've put an "*" next to the lines which give me this error. Using Eclipse btw. The whole code is linked below. Thanks!!

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        openFile();
        addRecords();
        closeFile();
    }
    public static void openFile()
    {
        try
        *{
        *   output = new Formatter("numbers.txt");
        *}
        *catch
        {
            System.err.println("Write permission denied. Terminating.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        *catch
        {
            System.err.println("Error opening file. Terminating.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

http://pastebin.com/CKPQzCNi

Comment: You have two `catch`(es). What kind of `Exception`(s) are you trying to `catch`? What names should those `Exception`(s) have?

Comment: I FEEL SO DUMB RIGHT NOW.

Comment: Thanks everyone! (now how to I go about closing a thread)?

Comment: @Walby take a look at this [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96281/how-to-close-a-question-in-stackoverflow-com) to see how to close your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `catch` clause is an exception handler which takes in an argument. The argument type, *ExceptionType* must be declared and must be the name of a class that inherits from the `Throwable` class. I see your `try-catch` block is not specifying an argument to either of the `catch` clauses.

Refer to the method `addRecords()` in the code you have referenced on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/CKPQzCNi) for an example of correct exception handling.